# Dual boot problem, black screen during the ubuntu boot

Tags: boot, uefi, grub-efi

I have a problem with my dual boot (windows 8 and ubuntu 13.1) on my asus vivo book.
Actually I'm writing from a live of linux-secure-remix and I already used the boot repair tools.
I can access and use Windows 8, but I can't boot with Ubuntu (also with recovery mode), the process is interrupted after few seconds.
Here, there is my summary report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6416043/

Can you help me?

Daniele

Comment: Please elaborate: What do you mean by "the process is interrupted after few seconds?" For instance, does the computer hang, reboot, or do something else? What, if anything, do you see on the screen? When you boot Windows, do you boot it via GRUB or via the computer's own boot manager? If the latter, are you able to bring up GRUB or not?

Comment: When I try to boot with Ubuntu in recovery mode, I can see only the "loading initial ramdisk" and then the machine is stuck. I can select Windows boot from Grub. Grub is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running into one of many "blank screen" problems that have been common in the past year or so. See, for example, these questions on this site:

- [Ubuntu 13.04 on UEFI system hangs at black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340223/ubuntu-13-04-on-uefi-system-hangs-at-black-screen)
- [Ubuntu 12.10 - Black screen after GRUB, can't install. UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272728/ubuntu-12-10-black-screen-after-grub-cant-install-uefi)
- [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

There are many others, too; try [this Web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22black+screen%22+uefi+site%3Aaskubuntu.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) to see them.

Unfortunately, there is no one "magic bullet" solution, because these problems have multiple causes that require distinct solutions for each individual cause.

Comment: I solved. I don't know very well how, but here there is the new summary report obtained with boot-repair. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6421041/ Thx