# Ubuntu 12.04 Dual Boot fails to load (black screen)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, crash

I have a dual boot Windows 7 + Ubuntu 12.04 system (64 bit).  About a week ago, using GRUB to load into Ubuntu resulted in a freeze at the loading screen.  I could still run into recovery mode, so using the console from that I tried a few solutions I found on the web.
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
    sudo apt-get install fglrx
    sudo aticonfig --initial
    sudo reboot
No luck there. Then I tried updating the Nvidia drivers (GTX 760):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

Still nothing. In fact, now I just get a black screen with a blinking cursor when I boot into Ubuntu regularly.  I can still boot into recovery mode, and can not find a solution.  Text appears when I shut down off the blinking cursor screen  (it turns purple, and says something like "terminating ubuntu").  I am a new user to linux, and the most advanced thing I've done in terminal is using the nano editor.

This may be important, so about a week before this error started, I used a partition tool to increase Ubuntu's main partition to 100 gigs.  After that, both Ubuntu and Windows still worked normally, until the error described above.  Windows still works fine (Posting this question while in Windows on the same machine).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first boot from live ubuntu cd and go to termianl by ctlr+alt+T and just use the command below,

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

this help me when i have problem after install ubuntu alongside with windows, hope this will help you too.

Comment: Nope, same effect as before

Comment: Try this  http://askubuntu.com/questions/376952/dual-boot-problem-black-screen-during-the-ubuntu-boot

Comment: Same result as before