# Ubuntu problem after changing some video settings

Tags: drivers, video

I did some settings (I don't remember for sure what settings) following a tutorial and trying to make ubuntu to see my monitor and to let me change the resolution.

After a restart I see just a black screen. Is anything that I can do to get back on initial settings?

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly impossible to help you with so little information.

Shot in the dark.

Delete your`xorg.conf` because your X server generate them for you.

```
# make a backup
tar cfvz backup-xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf*
# and delete all self generated files
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf*
```

You could also try to install a minimal X system.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg
```

**Update** 
Look here, here and here ...

- [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)
- [Dual boot problem, black screen during the ubuntu boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376952/dual-boot-problem-black-screen-during-the-ubuntu-boot)
- https://www.google.de/search?q=ubuntu+boot+problem+black+screen

Comment: Sorry for this. I'm so newbie with ubuntu I don't know what information to provide. The problem is that I can't get on any console there to delete something. I get the grub, I select ubuntu, I see that is loading something and ... bam, black screen.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Look at the first two entries. Here are many solutions and links to look further.